# org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-format, threetenbp

I'm receiving the **date in the below format**:

> "Deadline": "2019-07-05T16:30:00"

And I'm trying to **parse it using below** formatter:

```
private val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-05-21T12:30:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Note: i'm using ThreeTenABP library

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library.

Comment: it is working for with java date time

Comment: Weird. Index 19 is the end of the string. Could there be some non-printing character at the end of your format pattern string? BTW you don’t need to declare your own formatter for this string. Just use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I've checked it.There isn't any character at the end of my format pattern string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Using jdk1.7.0_67, threetenbp-1.3.6 and your formatter I tried `LocalDateTime.parse("2019-05-21T12:30:00", formatter)`. It gave the expected result and no exception. Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: @OleV.V. The issue was from backend part the time format wasn't same but now it's fixed. Thanks for your time.